# How to retrieve list item from the custom list, on a content editor with some texts?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, custom-list, content-editor-web-part

As described from the question, i want to retrieve a list item and display it on a content editor. This should be most likely be using a javascript or jquery perharps?

UPDATES:
Here is an example: [image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to know basic javascript.

[**How to complete basic library operations using javascript**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-javascript-library-code-in-sharepoint)

Comment: Is there other alternative, besides Javascript?

Comment: Depends on how you want it formatted. You could place the list webpart on the page, hide the chrome and title, use some CSS to modify the style and modify the view to limit columns.

Comment: I have actually modified my view, however i do want to also add in some text on a content webpart, that include the value(s) of the list column(s).

Comment: Ah. Sounds like a report? Have you considered using Excel to connect to your list data? It could be an easy solution.

Comment: I want it to be responsive to the custom list but with using another view to just display out that 2 columns to that sentence above the list. I hope that's a way there. :)